# Bash script: parsing string with a command without executing it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that parses an xml in bash. I'm having a problem with one of the elements as it contains a string with some command inside of it:
i.e.:

```
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "*****  MONITORING  ***** \n\n Notification Type: Critical \n  Host:  &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.URL}   \n  Estado: &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status}    \n Time:    &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status_Timestamp}    Format: cyymmddhhmmssttt \n Contact to:APPSRV  "|/usr/bin/mail blabla@bla.com -c bllu@bluu.com -r "AAAAA" -s "**  MONITORING - Server URL -Critical  **"
```

How could I set that string into a variable (and print it) whithout executing the commands inside? I end up getting that printf in my output.

Thanks!

the code looks like this:

```
while read line
do

    if [[ $line == *"SITNAME"* ]] || [[ $line == *"TEXT"* ]] ; then
        flag=true
    fi


    if [ $flag= 'true' ]; then
        echo "$line"
        writeLine=$writeLine';'"$line"               
    fi


done < file.text

echo $writeLine >> report.out
writeLine=""
flag=false
```

OUTPUT ON THE ECHO

```
<![CDATA[/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** MONITORING  ***** nn Notification Type: Critical n  Host:  &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.URL}   n  Stat: &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status}    n Time:    &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status_Timestamp}    Format: cyymmddhhmmssttt n Contact to:APPSRV  "|/usr/bin/mail mail@mail.com  -r "MONITORING" -s "**  MONITORING - Server URL -Critical  **"]]>
```

OUTPUT ON THE FILE

```
<![CDATA[/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** MONITORING file1.txt readme.txt file.xml script.sh nn Notification Type: Critical n Host: &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.URL} n Stat: &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status} n Time: &{INTERNETMANAGED_URL00.Status_Timestamp} Format: cyymmddhhmmssttt n Contact to:APPSRV "|/usr/bin/mail mail@mail.com -r "MONITORING" -s "** MONITORING - Server URL -Critical **"]]>
```

Comment: What does your `bash` code look like? Typically, just reading text and assigning it to a variable should not execute any commands.

Comment: I edited the question with some of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in that code would execute a command read from `file.txt`. Is it your intent to include only lines containing "SITNAME" or "TEXT", or every line after a line containing "SITNAME" or "TEXT"?

Comment: The filter is intentional. Also if I do: echo "$line"
                                writeLine=$writeLine';'"$line"  I get the output in console just fine but when I check report.out it has the output of the printf in the text.

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

writeLine="$writeLine"';'"$line"

...

echo "$writeLine" >> report.out

Thanks all for your time!

Comment: The problem was that since you didn't quote `$writeline`, the asterisks were being processed as a glob, which were expanded to the files in the current directory.

Comment: It isn't necessary to quote `$writeLine` or `$line` in `writeLine="$writeLine"';'"$line"`, because pathname expansion is not performed in variable assignments. However, as the `;` must be quoted, the assignment could be simplified to `writeLine=$writeLine";"$line` or `writeLine="$writeLine;$line"` as well.